# Writing a custom Rasa component to preprocess text in pipeline

Tags: python, nlp, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

We are trying to write a custom component for our rasa pipeline (using [rasa OS](https://rasa.com)), but can't seem to get it to work. This is what we currently have:

```
from rasa.nlu.components import Component

class PreProcessing(Component):
    """A custom sentiment analysis component"""
    name = "preprocessing"

    provides = []
    requires = []
    defaults = {}
    language_list = []

    def __init__(self, component_config=None):
        super(PreProcessing, self).__init__(component_config)

    def process(self, message, **kwargs):
        """Retrieve the tokens of the new message, pass it to the classifier
            and append prediction results to the message class."""
        
        return message.lower() # here, process text somehow. For example lowercase on input
```

and the `config.yml` file looks like:

```
language: "../../language_models/nb_core_news_lg"
recipe: default.v1

# Read the following docs on how to fine-tune a model using config.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/tuning-your-model#component-lifecycle

pipeline:

  - name: "preprocessing.PreProcessing" 

  ## Required pipeline components ##
  - name: SpacyNLP
    # note: this path is relative to ./live-bots/bot_name, where it's imported.
    model: "../../language_models/nb_core_news_lg"
    case_sensitive: False
    ...
```

This however does not seem to be working. The preprocessing of the text is not being picked up by the component SpacyNLP. Our custom component does not need to be trained, but the input text just needs to be processed. Any tips?